# How to implement AWS S3 Multipart Upload with Rails and Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, file-upload, rails-activestorage

I'm using vanilla Rails Active Storage file upload with multiple:true option. The files are stored on S3. The setup is working well. However, I was thinking for very large files it would be beneficial to implement Multipart Upload for optimal speed and reliability.

I found a description of AWS S3 multipart upload here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

I also found a Ruby specific page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu-ruby-sdk.html

However, I couldn't find any reference on how to implement this feature with Rails and Active Storage.

I would like to receive some direction on how best to go about implementing multipart upload without ripping out Active Storage if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case somebody is looking for an answer on this. Active Storage will support multipart upload starting from Rails 6.1. Active Storage direct upload automatically switches to multipart for large files. No settings changes are required.

You can customise the threshold for what is considered a large file. The default is 100MB, and you can change the default by adding this to your storage.yml under the amazon settings:
upload:
    multipart_threshold: <%= 250.megabytes %>

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: as far as I have been able to test, multipart uploads (from current rails master branch) do not happen as direct uploads to s3. `activestorage.js` has no change diffing master with v6.0.0.rc1. I haven't tested normal (not direct) uploads yet.

Comment: Support comes from 6.1. according to a Rails dev, who works on this part of the code.

Comment: Can someone show me where rails 6.1 multi-part upload code is? I believe it works on regular uploads, but not direct.

Comment: @AncorCruz I guess it is still not in `activestorage.js`, right?  https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/main/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.js

Comment: @AncorCruz any news on that? https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37316#issuecomment-1476439764